Bourbaki measure theory
I want to learn measure theory from the Bourbaki books. Would anyone happen to know what books in their elements of mathematics are strictly required to learn it.
For now I have the first book on set theory, algebra and (general) topology. Currently working on the second topology book.
From my experience, although they list all the previous books in the series as a prerequisite for the next ones, that doesn't seem to always be the case, for example the first book on general topology requires very little from the algebra books. Does that hold true up to measure theory or am I wrong in thinking so?
In this context I was wondering what books I should be focusing on.
Alternatively, I also read the first book of "Elements d'analyse" by Dieudonné, think that series starts talking about measure theory on the second or third books, is that more worthwhile?
Also, for now I'm not considering buying books outside of those two series - will eventually touch up on category theory for instance; but I have other priorities right now.

As Dieudonné was one of the most prolific writer in Bourbaki team for a long while, all the "matter" you will find in the books "Elements d'Analyse" will not be presented in a different way in Bourbaki. It is probably a good think to privilegize "Eléments d'Analyse" (measure theory is in chapters XIII and XIV of the second volume) which is clear enough, once you are accustomed to its style.

The approach used by Bourbaki for Measure Theory is not the most general one nor most common one.
